# How to understand "he'd be lucky to escape Azkaban" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Dumbledore was trying to sort it all out ... what did that mean? how much power did Dumbledore have to override the Ministry of Magic? Was there a chance that he might be allowed back to Hogwarts, then? A small shoot of hope burgeoned in Harry's chest, almost immediately strangled by panic—how was he supposed to refuse to surrender his wand without doing magic? He'd have to duel with the Ministry representatives, and if he did that, **he'd be lucky to escape Azkaban**, let alone expulsion.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*</sub>

I don't quite understand the meaning of "*he'd be lucky to escape Azkaban*". On the other hand, why didn't it put "he'd be lucky to escape **from** Azkaban"? How should we understand it in this context?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The meaning is:

> He'd be lucky to escape **being sent to Azkaban**.
>   He'd be lucky to **avoid** Azkaban.

Or

> He'd be lucky to escape **being sentenced to serve a term in Azkaban**.

That's why there's no **from**. The sentence does not speak about an attempt to escape from the prison.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't get the whole sentence is saying: "*He'd have to duel with the Ministry representatives, and if he did that, he'd be lucky to escape Azkaban, let alone expulsion.*" Can you help to explain it a bit?

Comment: @dan - If Harry fights against Ministry workers, the Wizard Court will not only expel him from Hogwarts but also send him to the Azkaban prison. If Harry does not fight, they will take away his wand.

Comment: Maybe, "he's lucky to..." confused me. It's not really 'lucky'. Is it a colorful way to express it?

Comment: @dan - It's not "**he is** lucky to", it's "**he would be** lucky to". The word **would** implies "if". **If** he escaped a prison sentence after fighting with officials, he **would be** considered quite a lucky boy.

Comment: I really think this answer would benefit from noting that "he'd be lucky to escape jail" or "he'd be lucky to escape prison" is a very well established phrase in English, and JKR has substituted 'Azkaban' as a magical equivalent

Comment: @Au101 From an AmE perspective, I see various ill fates in the phrase "lucky to escape X" (and in older literature, I've seen "the noose" and "the hangman"), so I think the phrase is pretty generic already.

Comment: @chrylis Sure :) It's just that, from my experience of Harry Potter, there are many instances where words, phrases and so on are consciously and pleasingly "wizarding-world-ed" (if you see what I mean). And this seems like a quite clear "wizarding-world-ification" ( :P ) of "he'd be lucky to escape jail"

Answer (score 9):

Further to CowperKettle's correct answer...

**escape** can be used as a transitive verb:

> He was charged with treason but escaped imprisonment by pleading insanity.
>
> The art thief escaped detection by dressing as a security guard.

There it can be understood to mean "managed to avoid".

> He escaped the island on a raft.

There it means "freed himself from the confinement of the island", and there you can use *from* if you like: "...escaped *from* the island..."